# mysql CONVERT() and CAST() to integer are increasing the value by 1

Tags: mysql, casting

I'm trying to select records from a phone-call table where the value of an ENUM string field called `Call_Rating` is less than the integer value 4. The `Call_Rating` field can only contain the values '0','1','2','3','4','5'. Whenever I use `CONVERT(Call_Rating, UNSIGNED INTEGER)` or `CAST(Call_Rating AS UNSIGNED)`, the values of the `Call_Rating` field are increased by 1. Why is it doing this and is there a way to avoid it other than just manually subtracting 1 from the CALL() or CAST() functions?
**Also, this is an old DB that was set-up by someone else and is still in use by various systems, so some way of getting around this issue without changing the DB schema would be useful.**

#### Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE `member_calls` (
  `CallID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Call_Rating` enum('0','1','2','3','4','5') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CallID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=538616 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### Data in Table

```
INSERT INTO `member_calls`
  (`CallID`, `Call_Rating`)
VALUES
  (510515, '4'),
  (510909, '0'),
  (538614, '3'),
  (538615, '5');
```

#### Select Statement

```
SELECT `CallID`, `Call_Rating`, CAST(`Call_Rating` AS UNSIGNED) AS 'Casted', CONVERT(`Call_Rating`, UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS 'Converted'
FROM `member_calls`
WHERE CONVERT(`Call_Rating`, SIGNED INTEGER) < 4
   OR CAST(`Call_Rating` AS UNSIGNED) < 4;
```

#### Given Results

```
CallID  Call_Rating Casted  Converted
510909  0           1       1
```

#### Expected Results

```
CallID  Call_Rating Casted  Converted
510909  0           0       0
538614  3           3       3
```

## Edit 2016-5-17

Thank you everyone for your input. I now understand why the issue was happening. Basically the ENUM was being treated like an array and CAST()/CONVERT() were returning the index of the array rather than the value. The best solution to this would be to change the ENUM to an INT field, but that is not desirable in my situation since the DB is being used live, and altering the data type could cause issues elsewhere. For that reason, lserni's solution was the most useful for me.

Comment: The problem likely is connected to your using an ENUM. Any specific reason why you need to use that rather than a TINYINT?

Comment: Thanks pekka. I definitely agree that it probably should be an integer field, and I might end up having to change it to that, but as I mentioned in my question this is an old database that was set up by someone else and is integrated with other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct conversion of ENUM to INTEGER yields the index of that ENUM, and since they start from 1, the first element is 0 and becomes 1, etc.

**It's not increasing by 1 at all**: it's returning an integer value **that by chance seems as it's the correct value plus 1**. But it could be anything else. If you had an enum of '1','2','3','4','5', without the '0', then the result would *appear* to be correct, even if it really isn't.

Either run a double convert passing from CHAR, or an implicit convert again after converting to CHAR:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(Call_Rating, CHAR(1)), UNSIGNED), 0+CONVERT(Call_Rating, CHAR(1)), 0+Call_Rating, CAST(Call_Rating AS UNSIGNED) from member_calls;


+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| CONVERT(CONVERT(Call_Rating, CHAR(1)), UNSIGNED) | 0+CONVERT(Call_Rating, CHAR(1)) | 0+Call_Rating | CAST(Call_Rating AS UNSIGNED) |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
|                                                2 |                               2 |             3 |                             3 |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It best fit the situation I was in in that I don't necessarily want to change the table's schema.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give a detailed explanation of what is happening here, but it's likely to do with the fact that you are using an ENUM with numeric values, instead of  an INT type, which seems like the sane choice.

The mySQL manual [strongly recommends against this:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html#enum-sorting)

> We strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as enumeration values, because it does not save on storage over the appropriate TINYINT or SMALLINT type, and it is easy to mix up the strings and the underlying number values (which might not be the same) if you quote the ENUM values incorrectly. If you do use a number as an enumeration value, always enclose it in quotation marks. If the quotation marks are omitted, the number is regarded as an index. See Handling of Enumeration Literals to see how even a quoted number could be mistakenly used as a numeric index value.

mySQL is probably using the numeric index instead of the ENUM value and that's causing the weirdness.

Just switch to a proper INT field.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It really should be changed to an integer, but I'd rather avoid having to do that since the table is actively being used by other systems.

Answer (score 1):

You should get that `ENUM` is not string or integer that is enum.

To me that is the type you should avoid in DB as much as possible.

Here is fiddle tha illustrate why that happens to you:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de53b2/1

as you can see when mysql casting ENUM to int - that returns something like index of saved value in array(enum) but not the value casted to int.

But just to illustrate mysql power functionality you can run this query to get expected result:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2cf5/3

```
SELECT `CallID`, `Call_Rating`,
  ELT(CAST(`Call_Rating` AS UNSIGNED),'0','1','2','3','4','5') AS 'Casted', 
  ELT(CONVERT(`Call_Rating`, SIGNED INTEGER),'0','1','2','3','4','5') AS 'Converted'
FROM `member_calls`
HAVING `Casted` < 4
   OR `Converted` < 4;
```

But anyway that is not best solution. 
I think you should better redesign your db schema.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might end up changing the field to an integer, but I'd rather avoid that since the table is actively being used by other systems.